# ElasticSearch Spring-Data - Date string converts automatically into date field while saving

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am saving object in elasticsearch. There is a field in which some value can be:

1: **today is Wednesday**

2: **2018-10-12**

First data saved successfully but when I am trying to send second data as string. Spring boot elasticsearch automatically converts it into date and send below exception:

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=mapper [factValues.factValue] cannot be changed from type [date] to [text]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=mapper [factValues.factValue] cannot be changed from type [date] to [text]]]
```

As I have defined this field

```
Field(type = Text)
private String factValue;
```

Why its sending date field in it?

Its been 2 days for me. I am stuck here

Comment: what is the mapping for this field in the index

Comment: @Document(indexName = "patentindex", type = "patents")

Comment: Can we disable auto mapping and accept only text in any case

Comment: that's not the mapping. what does calling Elasticsearch with GET /patentindex/_mapping return? How was the index created? By your application?